# Ethernet adapter stuck at 10 Mbit/s

Tags: ethernet

My Ethernet adapter is somehow stuck at 10 Mbit/s. Here's the output of `ethtool eth0`:

```
Settings for eth0:
    Supported ports: [ TP MII ]
    Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
    Supported pause frame use: No
    Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
    Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Full 
    Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
    Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Link partner advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                                         100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
    Link partner advertised pause frame use: Symmetric
    Link partner advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Speed: 10Mb/s
    Duplex: Full
    Port: MII
    PHYAD: 0
    Transceiver: internal
    Auto-negotiation: on
    Current message level: 0x00000007 (7)
                   drv probe link
    Link detected: yes
```

As you can see, my adapter supports 100 Mbit/s, and the "link partner" (my router?) supports 100 Mbit/s. However, if I manually set the mode to 100 Mbit/s using `sudo ethtool -s eth0 speed 100 duplex full` the link immediately disconnects.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: how do you know it is the adapter that is the problem?  There are number of things that could be an issue....what other troubleshooting have you done?

Comment: How did I imply it's the adapter that is the problem?

Comment: Connect the pc to another router or switch. Or connect another pc to the router using your wire.

Comment: Other PCs use 100MiB/s correctly :/

Comment: Can you post the output of `ethtool -i eth0`, `dmesg | grep eth0`, `grep . /sys/class/net/eth0/device/{subsystem_,}{device,vendor}` and `udevadm info --export-db | awk -vRS= /eth0/`

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried (while the system is on) turning the interface off and on?  I'll assume that you have rebooted your system and this is something consistently happening.

Use a different cable.  Bad cables or connectors do happen.  Also of note, make sure you are using the right Cat of cable.

Use a different router/switch port.  The router/switch port might be bad.

Examine configuration of router/switch port, is it auto negotiating?  is the speed fixed? If you try to do auto on a port that has a fixed speed, I have seen what you have specified happen.

Some adapter boards do not properly do auto negotiation.  If that is the case, then manually set both the router/switch port to a fixed speed.

Finally replace adapter board with new board and go through the troubleshooting including above.

Your final option is that the switch/router is bad.

Comment: I've tried everything. I turned autonegotiating off: it dies whenever I manually set 100 MiB/s. I connected the cable to another PC; works at 100 MiB/s. I am beginning to suspect this is simply a shitty interface (I bought it at a cheap Chinese store; it doesn't even have a brand on it) that falsely advertises 100 MiB/s support to the OS.

Comment: do you have access to the router/switch?  You sound as if this is not the case, I'd advise working with the site systems admin to verify the router/switch configuration.

Comment: Why are you assuming so many stuff? I am simply at home, and I can configure anything about the router, and control the entire network.

Comment: without information in the question, I can only guess.

Comment: BTW, looks like it is time to get a new timex (adapter board) from what you are saying.